How to clip a ModelEntity in VisionOS when using RealityKit
I want to cut some portion of a ModelEntity like half cutting a cube and show inner part to users. Can this be achieved? Entities can be clipped when in Volume, I want to achieve this in immersion space.
I have searched a lot but no solution.
